# An Error With Using Log.i()

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a service in android studio(2.1.2) and I need to use Log.i() , but I have this error :The logging tag can be at most 23 characters. now I don't know how can I fix it !.

Here are my codes:

```
package com.example.n5110.intent;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG ="com.example.n5110.intent";
public MyService() {
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG,"onStartCommand called");

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+ 5000;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime){
                    synchronized (this){
                        try{
                            wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            Log.i(TAG,"Service is busy");
                        }catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread buckysThread = new Thread(r);
    buckysThread.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy called");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your tag shorter. Do you really need this tag in logs?

`private static final String TAG ="MyService: ";`

This should be enough

Comment: you meant the tag can be anything... I'm a beginner in android , but thanks.

Comment: @M.ds tag is only for you, to make logs more readable, so you can detect in which class/activity/part of project error occured, or info printed

Answer (score 1):

> The logging tag can be at most 23 characters

The tag is the first parameter in your `Log.i()` call. It is `TAG`, defined as `com.example.n5110.intent`. That is 24 characters long. So, remove 1+ characters from your `TAG` constant.

Comment: but my package name is : com.example.n5110.intent ,

Comment: @M.ds: The tag does not have to be your package name.

Comment: in this case it's my package name, and with this package name i used Log.i() before . but right now it gives me this error.

Comment: @M.ds: They changed something to put a 23-character cap on the tag, apparently.